# Best way to monitor GC for java 8 spring service and display that on grafana using prometheus

Tags: java, spring, prometheus, monitoring, grafana

I'm trying to create a dashboard that will have a traffic light for the health of my service. The service is a spring boot java 8 service with all the spring metrics exposed. However I do not know the best way to display when the service is having trouble with garbage collection and so would like to make a graph on grafana to display this.
What metrics would be best to look at and to compare to each other?

Answer (score 0):

spring boot collect VM metrics by default that contains with prometheus :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-metrics/docs/current/public/prometheus#meter-registries

After that you need to mount grafana over prometheus.